# Whats wrong with this redirect meta refresh

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have this code here:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5" url="<? if($saydim=="0") { 
echo "$site/search.php?load=$search"; }
else { 
echo "$site/v-$seoo-$idd.html"; } ?>" />
```

The redirect is not working properly with this if else statment, just keeps refreshing the same page and dont redirects to the if url or the else url, at the source code i cannot see anything wrong.

I appreciate any suggestions you may have to fix this.

Comment: Accept the Answer or Comment on what is still wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct syntax: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">`

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5;URL='<? if($saydim=="0") { 
echo "$site/search.php?load=$search"; }
else { 
echo "$site/v-$seoo-$idd.html"; } ?>' />
```

or short version:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5;URL='<?php echo ($saydim=="0") ? "$site/search.php?load=$search" : "$site/v-$seoo-$idd.html"; ?>'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5;url='<?php echo ($saydim=="0") ? "$site/search.php?load=$search":"$site/v-$seoo-$idd.html"; ?>' />
```

use turnary operator instead

Comment: URL must be part of content attribute.

Comment: Ohhh.. I didn't look that one .. sorry.. I just formatted his if condition and used ternary operator :( Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Your meta syntax is wrong :

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5;URL=<? if($saydim=="0") { 
echo "$site/search.php?load=$search"; }
else { 
echo "$site/v-$seoo-$idd.html"; } ?>" />
```